# Interfacing Eclipse Workbench UI with GNU debugger functions

Tags: eclipse, gdb, eclipse-cdt, interaction

I want to know how the Eclipse Workbench UI communicates with the GNU debugger.
What I mean is in the Eclipse for C/C++, when we press the step over or resume or continue buttons in the menu, what happens behind the scenes?
As in how is the GNU gdb invoked? How does gdb know which function to execute? How does the UI communicate with gdb?
I have added a custom function to the gdb(does not matter what the function is..) and I want to add a button to the Eclipse workbench such that pressing the button will call the gdb and that function in particular.
I want to know how Eclipse workbench UI interacts with the GNU gdb.
How do I go about doing this?

Thanks,
Rohit

Answer (score 5):

See the "[Accessing gdb with the Eclipse CDT and MI](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-eclipse-cdt-debug2/index.html)" article.

> The GNU Debugger (gdb) is the most popular open source debugger in use. It's generally used as a command-line executable, but it can be accessed through software using the little-known MI protocol.
>
> - The C/C++ Debugger Interface (CDI) was created by Eclipse/CDT developers so CDT can access external debuggers.
> - The Machine Interface (MI) was created by gdb developers so external applications can access the gdb.
>
> In many cases, the MI result record is followed by (gdb) and an out-of-band (OOB) record. These records provide additional information about the status of the target or the debugging environment.
>   The *stopped message after -exec-step is an OOB record that provides information about breakpoints, watchpoints, and why the target has halted or finished.
>   In the previous session, gdb returns *stopped,reason="end-stepping-range" after each -exec-step, along with the status of the target.
>
> gdb/MI is hard for humans to understand, but it's ideal for communication between software processes.
>   **The CDT enables this communication by creating a pseudo-terminal (pty) that sends and receives data. Then, it starts gdb and creates two session objects to manage debug data.**
>
> The MI-CDI-wrapper-Eclipse communication is useful only if it updates Eclipse's graphical display with proper debug data.

[image]

> When you right-click an entry in the Signals View, the Resume with Signal  context-menu option lets you continue the target's execution and send the selected signal to the process.
>   This option calls on the `SignalsActionDelegate`.
>   When this option is selected, the delegate calls on the CDI target to resume its execution with the `ICDISignal` corresponding to the selected signal.
>   The target creates an MI command for the signal and invokes MISession.postCommand(), which sends the command to gdb.
>
> When gdb responds, the process of updating the Signals View takes five steps:
>
> 1. The MISession analyzes the MI output from gdb and determines whether a signal setting is being changed. If so, it fires an MISignalChangedEvent.
> 2. The CDI EventManager listens for the MISignalChangedEvent and responds by creating a CDI event: ChangedEvent. Then it fires the event and alerts all ICDIEventListeners.
> 3. The CDebugTarget receives the event from the EventManager and determines whether the ChangedEvent relates to a signal change. If so, it calls on its CSignalManager to process the CDI event.
> 4. The CSignalManager updates its model elements and fires a DebugEvent whose type is given by DebugEvent.CHANGE.
> 5. The SignalViewEventHandler receives the DebugEvent, checks to make sure it deals with signals, and refreshes the Signals View.
>
> Understanding the involved operation of the Signals View is important for two reasons;
>
> - It serves as a concrete example of how the different model elements work together, and
> - it shows how you can build similar views that interact with Eclipse, gdb, and the CDI.
>
> Conclusion

- Two session objects (`MISession` and `Session`),
- two targets (`CDebugTarget` and `Target`), and
- two completely different hierarchies of model elements

Comment: Thanks a lot VonC. This will surely help me. THanks again